# What's the last freeware version of ObjectDock?

Tags: windows, version

The [current latest version (2.1) of ObjectDock available for download from Stardock's website](http://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/download.asp) is now a trial version. I would like to [download the last free, non-trial version of ObjectDock](http://www.filehippo.com/download_objectdock/history/) but I would like to know what its version number is.

Anyone what the last freeware version of ObjectDock is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to chip.de](http://www.chip.de/downloads/ObjectDock_13006461.html) Version 2.0 seems to be the last Freeware version.